# How to create ArrayList of an object present within Arraylist?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have following use case

```
 class Agree{

 }

 class Agreebody{
    Agree agree;
 }

 class AgreeFull{
   List<AgreeBody> agreebody;
 }
```

The requirement is to create a List of all Agrees present inside AgreeBody List.

```
 List<Agree> l = new List<Agree>
 agreeFull.getAgreeBody.stream(). ? //Need to get Agree from Each agreebody and make list of agrees
```

Shall i call `.forEach` and do it manually or other better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)

```
List<Agree> l = agreeFull.getAgreebody().stream()
        .map(AgreeBody::getAgree)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You need also to focus on some part of your code, for example using getter and setters, significant name for the attributes and class..